# Why do I get 'Float object is not callable' error

Tags: python

I'm getting this error in my code:

```
Test Failed: 'float' object is not callable.
```

My code is as follows:

```
import math

class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def std_dev(persons):
    persons_age = [person.age for person in persons]
    mean = float(sum(persons_age) * 1.0)/len(persons)
    length = float(len(persons))
    mean = float(mean(persons))
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(length):
        total_sum += float(persons_age[i]- mean)**2
    square_root = float((total_sum * 1.0)/length)
    return math.sqrt(square_root)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Easiest way for code these days is 3 backticks "```" before and after, github-markdown style .   Or, you can indent each code line 4 spaces, but that's kind of a pain.  See my edit.

Comment: The traceback fo that error will tell you on which line the error occurs which is the most efficient way of debugging it. Can you include that?  You'll note the code snippet you provide is not a complete, verifiable example so I can't reproduce it myself.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This simple example reproduces your error:

```
In [101]: x = 1.23                                                              
In [102]: x()                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-08f9d0828de0> in <module>
----> 1 x()

TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

That means, some place in your code, you define a variable as a number, float.  And then later you use that variable as though it were a function, with ().

The full traceback should identify which line and variable is the problem.  But `mean` is a good guess.

What is this supposed to do?

```
mean(persons)
```

There is a `numpy.mean` function, but not a base Python one.

On an unrelated matter, you don't need all of those calls to `float(...)`.  In Py3, float division is the norm.  So there's no harm in leaving integers that way.  Normally you only need `float` if the argument is a string.